# I can't render with GPU no matter what project I'm on

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu, error

Firstly, sorry for my english and I'm a very beginner in blender.
I made something in blender, changed to Cycles and tried to render in viewport. Normally, it would take something like 30 seconds to render but it stuck on "Path Tracing Sample : 1/32". It isn't a big project. On other projects it is fast but on the project that I just created, it is very very slow. I decided to use my GPU for faster rendering but when I go in rendered preview it says : "Cancel" When I render, it shows "CUDA error at cuCtxCreate: Launch exceeded timeout". It happens quick, like in seconds it rendering nothing and showing that error on top. I tried render other projects with GPU and it giving same error.
Can someone help me?

Edit : I fixed the extremely slow render time by deleting the carpet on my project :)

Comment: Going to ask: What video card are you running?

Comment: GTX 1050 Ti with gaming drivers.